How do I exit from nested shells at the command line without accidentally closing/exiting my terminal?
If I am typing in a terminal and do this
% bash
% [enter many commands in this shell]
% bash
% [enter many commands in this shell]
. . .

(could be zsh instead of bash) and I forget how many shells deep I am and want to get back to the top-level shell, how do I do it without accidentally closing my terminal?
The dangerous thing I try to do is
% exit
% exit
% exit

and if I enter one more exit than I need, I unintentionally close my terminal, possibly losing work.  It can ruin a day.
Answers that aren't good enough:
I know I could scroll up or do a search in the terminal for the commands, but that's painful and isn't always possible.  I know I could avoid this situation in the future with tricks in my environment or by just never creating new shells like that, but that doesn't answer the question.  If I'm lucky, my command prompt changes, so I know I'm at the top when the prompt changes back, assuming I notice.  But, let's say it doesn't change.  Note that entering history at the command line doesn't help because the history of the previous shell typically doesn't carry over.  Entering return doesn't help.
If my computer (a Mac) keeps history for all shells somewhere, that sounds like a potential guaranteed solution, but is that typical?  It also still sounds painful to sift through.  I'm hoping for a better answer, like a simple command that uses ps to show me my stack of nested shells in the current terminal.  Keep in mind that I might have many terminal windows.

Look at the result of ps -fp $$, do you see -bash or bash?

Similar to @WalterA 's comment: echo $0.  If it starts with a -, you're probably at the initial shell.

ps -p$(ps -p$$ -oppid=) will show the parent process. If it's another shell, it's safe to exit.

As the writer of the question, I find these suggestions from Gairfowl and Walter A great.  I know enough to make those work for me and answers my question.  I don't know if others will, but these seem like good basis for an answer.

You might want to take a look at screen which also helps if a remote connection is lost or the shell quits unexpectedly. You can reconnect to any running process and not lose data.

I always configure by prompt so that it shows the shell level (nesting level of shells). In bash, this is stored in the variable SHLVL. In zsh, this is performed by the prompt escape %L.

@Ed Morton, in this particular case, I was testing the behavior of shells, learning that functions and aliases do not pass on to sub-shells like environment variables do.  But, I've been in this situation at other times.  I might login to a machine where my shell is tcsh by default but I need to be in bash.  I might start a new bash because I want to throw away environment variable changes when I'm done.  Sometimes, you run a script and it can add a shell and not exit out.  There are other cases, too.

[Inspired by Gairfowl's comments] You could add something like this to your .bashrc and .zshrc:
unshell() {
    case "$0" in
        -*) echo "Already at top-level shell" >&2 ;;
        *sh*)
            parent="$(ps -ocomm= -p$(ps -p$$ -oppid=))"
            case "$parent" in
                -*) echo "Exiting to top" >&2 ;;
                *sh* ) echo "Not at top yet" >&2 ;;
                * ) echo "Not sure what the parent process ($parent) is." >&2 ;;
            esac
            exit ;;
        * ) echo "\$0 is weird ($0); not sure what to do." >&2 ;;
    esac
}

You'll still have to run it multiple times to exit out of multiple levels of shells, but it won't exit from the top level, and will let you know when you've exited the last sub-level shell.

This is a technically correct answer to my question.  It might be worth explicitly saying that you paste this into your terminal to define the unshell function, then you need to enter unshell to run it, and you have to repeat if "Not at top yet".   I was really just looking for an explanation for what the echo $0 and ps -p$(ps -p$$ -oppid=) commands do exactly, breaking them down and describing what $0 and $$ are,  how to use the commands, and what to expect to see when you are in the top shell and when you're not.  I'm hoping an edit might get all of that in here.

Assuming that you have recent version of bash (4.X and up), consider two options. Both of them require small change to the .profile or .bash_login or equivalent on your account:

Bash maintain the 'SHLVL' environment variable - incrementing it on every level. You can add it to the prompt: export PS1='\s-($SHLVL)$ '. You can visually see what level you are at any point in time.

bash-(1)$ bash
bash-(2)$ bash
bash-(3)$ exit
bash-(2)$ exit
bash-(1)$exit



Another option will be to change the 'exit' command - requiring different command to exit a top level shell. If you bash is login shell (e.g., from ssh), you do not need an extra command ('bye' below) - logout is already set to exit login shells.

if [[ "${SHLVL-1}" = 1 ]] ; then
    alias exit='echo enter "bye" to exit this shell'
    alias bye='builtin exit'
fi


@CharlesDuffy - thanks for checking. I was typing on my ipad. Sometimes I forget how easy it is to make 4 typos in 4 lines - with syntax highlighting. I'll fix. Why can't csh/bash/zsh/... all agree on identical syntax for one simple comment :-(

well, csh can't agree to anything because substantive development happened in the 70s and it's been effectively dead -- just with clones making minor changes around the edges -- almost as long as I've been alive. POSIX.2 is the standard by which shells agreed to have a consistent subset of syntax, but zsh deliberately breaks that standard because they think parts of it are stupid. (They're right -- parts of it are stupid, but I tend to argue that this is a place where consistent is more important than right).

zsh and bash agree on the name SHLVL, at least, for tracking shell depth. (And as both export it, nesting zsh inside bash and vice versa works as expected.)

On my red hat 7 - using tcsh - SHLVL seems to work. Not sure if it’s generic out of the box, or something the local admin configured.

You could use an environment variable to count the levels by just incrementing it upon spawning a new shell.
For example, add export BASH_LEVEL=$((BASH_LEVEL+1)) to your .bashrc, then start a new Bash shell:
$ bash
$ echo $BASH_LEVEL 
1

$ bash
$ echo $BASH_LEVEL
2

$ exit
$ echo $BASH_LEVEL 
1

You could also show this variable in your shell prompt, e.g using PS1='…bash/${BASH_LEVEL}…' would display bash/1, bash/2 etc.


I'm looking for a way to deal with the situation once in it, not how to avoid it.

Alternatively, with pstree from psmisc, you could show a list of all parent processes down to the current process using pstree -s $$. For example (-A makes it use ASCII lines):
$ bash
$ pstree -As $$
systemd---wm---kitty---bash---pstree

$ bash
$ pstree -As $$
systemd---wm---kitty---bash---bash---pstree

$ exit
$ pstree -As $$
systemd---wm---kitty---bash---pstree


I'm looking for a way to deal with the situation once in it, not how to avoid it.

psmisc solves the problem--thanks.  I'm holding out for something that doesn't require me to install something.  From comments from Gairfowl, there appears to be a simpler approach.  If you get rid of the first part of this or swap the bottom with the top, I'll upvote and remove/edit comments.

@bjc Building on Gairfowl's approach, you could check if the parent process exists in /etc/shells, and if so, exit: grep -Fxq "$(ps -p$(ps -p$$ -oppid=) -oexe=)" /etc/shells && exit
